# Objective-C Xcode - if statement "Expected expression"

Tags: objective-c

i must check if the interval between 2 times is > 0 then set the text of a label but i get "Expected expression" when i use the if statement..

```
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *newDateString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:now];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:newDateString];
NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:@"15:00:00"];
NSTimeInterval interval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
int hours = (int)interval / 3600; // integer division to get the hours part
int minutes = (interval - (hours*3600)) / 60; // interval minus hours part (in seconds) divided by 60 yields minutes
int seconds = interval - ((hours*3600)+(minutes*60)) ;
NSString *timeDiff = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d | %02d | %02d", hours, minutes, seconds];

if (interval < 0)
{
self.before3.text = timeDiff;
}
```

The error is on `if (interval < 0)`

Can someone help me please?

Regards.

Comment: This looks like it should work. Is this your actual code or did you leave something out? Could also be some funky unicode character that snuck in there, try remove the whole if line and *type* it again. Also take a look at `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar` instead of doing those data calculations yourself.

Comment: Do you have a stray character, or a missing brace or something in your code?  That's the first thing to look for.

Comment: Is not the full code, if i remove the "if(...)" and use only "self.before3.text = timeDiff;" is all ok but if i add the if statement i got the error.. Tried to delete and rewrite it, all semi colon and brackets are ok..

Comment: Yes, when you remove the line, remove it all the way back to and including the `;` on the prior line.  Then retype by hand (don't copy/paste).

Comment: Already done.. Also closed then reopened Xcode and cleaned the project.

Comment: (There's no chance that you have a `#define if garbage` somewhere is there?)

Comment: (Enter an dummy `if` statement up near the top -- like right after the first line: `if (now) { NSLog("%@", now);}`.  See if it compiles.)

Comment: Rewrited (again) the if on another Mac.. Today it works... Stupid Xcode. Thanks to all!